# Bigquery API call result missing and different from direct query on cloud

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running Google BigQuery through API call at Google Cloud instance. However, the result is different from what I can get from direct query, say, I should get 1000 line of result form the query.
From API call, I can get around 500 results each time (different results each time). Nearly half of information is missing for the query. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like that by default you get only the first page. Did you use [getQueryResults](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/getQueryResults)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier      query_results = bigquery_client.run_sync_query(q);
    query_results.use_legacy_sql = True;
    query_results.run(); 
    return query_results.  This is what I used, any difference between this with getQueryResults

Comment: remember to page through the results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I get the answer. Query result has a limit of 10 MB of data. Once it exceeds this limit, on web UI, you cannot save as CSV and should save as table. The same rule applies to API call.